# Prove that the Laplace expansion for the determinant is the same for any choice of row or column

Tags: matrices, determinant, laplace-expansion

So I understand from the definition of the determinant that: $$\det(A)=\sum_{i}^{} (-1)^{i+k}a_{ki}M_{ki}$$where we define $M_{ki}$ to be the determinant of an $(n-1) \times (n-1$) matrix formed by removing the $k$-th row and $i$-th column from $A$.

How can we show that, in general, any choice of $k$ will yield exactly the same determinant.
Also how can we show that the determinant can be found by expanding over a column rather than a row?

Comment: I know no way to show that expansion by different rows gives the same result other than to prove that they all give $\det A$. And, for your second question, I would argue that $\det(A^\top) = \det A$ (various ways to do that) and deduce it from that.

Comment: Ah yes, thanks for your answer with regards to the second point!